# PMD Ignore Spring Field Injections in gradle config

Tags: java, spring, gradle, pmd

Currently I have several Controllers that inject dependencies through a field marked with `@Autowired`. When I try to run `gradle build` the following violations come up.

[image]

These all correspond to the instances of where a spring component has been injected.

I am aware of the `ignoreAnnotations` property that seems to exist for PMD, however, I am not sure if one can actually specify this in a gradle configuration?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is: field injection is code smell and bad design practice.

When `@Autowired` is used on a non-transient field it can cause issues with serialization. This is because the field will not be properly initialized when the object is deserialized, leading to a `NullPointerException` when the object is used.

To fix this issue either make the fields transient or -- much better -- use constructor injection. To use constructor injection add a constructor to your class that takes all of the required dependencies as arguments, and annotate the constructor with @Autowired (the annotation is optional in modern Spring versions).

```
@Component
class MyClass {
    private final Dependency1 dependency1;
    private final Dependency2 dependency2;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(Dependency1 dependency1, Dependency2 dependency2) {
        this.dependency1 = dependency1;
        this.dependency2 = dependency2;
    }
}
```